# How do I import XML data to MySQL? (Linux hosting with cPanel from Godaddy)

Tags: php, mysql, xml

I am attempting to import XML data into a MySQL database but I don't know how to make this work. I am using Linux hosting with cPanel from Godaddy with php 5.4. This script is from a tutorial, but even after filling out the necessary MySQL login information, it results in a blank page and no information is being added to the database table. What am I doing wrong?

```
<?php

$url ="XML.php";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

$data = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$xml = simplexml_load_string($data);

$con=mysql_connect("localhost","dbusername","dbpassword");
mysql_select_db("dbname", $con) or die(mysql_error());

foreach ($xml -> item as $row) {
        $title = $row -> title;
        $description = $row -> description;
        $categories = $row -> categories;

$sql = "INSERT INTO 'test_xml' ('title', 'description', 'categories')"
            . "VALUES ('$title', '$description', '$categories')";

$result = mysql_query($sql);
if (!$result) {
    echo 'MySQL ERROR';
    } else {
    echo ' SUCCES';
    }

?>
```

Comment: Have you confirmed that the `test_xml` table has the correct fields?

Comment: I just double checked and everything looks ok.

Comment: You said you're getting a blank page. So are you not even seeing the "MySQL ERROR" text?

Comment: Do you have check error_log?

Comment: I am not sure. I am new to php and MySQL for the most part. I've never attempted anything like this.

Comment: I managed to get it to connect to the database, but it's still not showing in the database table.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34896757/5678086

Answer (score 1):

To fix the issue, Change your statement as below

Replace

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO 'test_xml' ('title', 'description', 'categories')"
        . "VALUES ('$title', '$description', '$categories')";
```

with

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO 'test_xml' ('title', 'description', 'categories')"
        . "VALUES ('".$title."', '".$description."', '".$categories."')";
```

Comment: Odd, the db table still isn't picking up any of the XML data. There must be something else I am doing wrong as well.